# Capturing failed request with ember-simple-auth

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am adding functionality to allow users to reject un-expired oauth tokens. (I am using ember-simple-auth-oauth2 and a custom oauth2 implimentation).

I would like to notify clients using a rejected token that their token was manually rejected.

The 401 response from the server contains the reason the token is no longer valid ({message: "Token was expired by ip 1.1.1.1"}).

None of the invalidationSucceeded callbacks or events in the session or application mixin seem to have the 401 request passed to this info.

Is there a way to access the body of the request that returned the 401 before the redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the adapter and override the ajaxError method. Following is the example:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';    
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
     host: url,

     ajaxError: function(jqXHR) {
         var error = this._super(jqXHR);

         if (jqXHR && jqXHR.status === 401) {
             var jsonErrors = Ember.$.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText)["errors"];                 
             return new DS.InvalidError(jsonErrors);
         } else {
             return error;
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: I ended up using this plus sessionStorage to achieve what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

401 Unauthorized will trigger the [`authorizationFailed` action](http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#SimpleAuth-ApplicationRouteMixin-authorizationFailed%60) if you're using the `ApplicationRouteMixin`. If you're not using the `ApplicationRouteMixin` you can subscribe to the session's [`authorizationFailed` event](http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#SimpleAuth-Session-authorizationFailed).

Comment: Yeah, I have been trying those two methods. Unfortunately I need access to the response body of the 401 which does not appear to be available in either. Is it possible to get it?

Comment: The response body isn't passed to the `authorizationFailed` action, you could setup your own `Ember.$(document).ajaxError` hook though.

Answer (score 0):

What if you override the authenticate action in your controller and handle the failure in there?

```
authenticate: function () {
  var promise = this._super(),
    _this = this;

  promise.then(function(result) {
    // code to do if succeeded
  }).catch(function(result) {
    // code to do if failed
  });
}
```

You just need to make sure that you call super to hand off the actual authenticate logic.