# How to redirect to login page if get the 401 error when I use ember-simple-auth?

Tags: javascript, authentication, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

```
"ember-simple-auth": "0.7.3"
```

My ember.js application model is not use ember data and use Ember.Object to set the ajax api url.

After I login successfuly, I change the token and I will get 401 errors. Like:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/account.json 401 (Unauthorized)
```

But the page is empty, if I am a user I don't know what is happen? I think if get the 401 error is redirect to login page is will be better.

So I try route error action:

```
  actions: {
    error: function(error, transition) {

      if (error && error.status === 401) {
        // error substate and parent routes do not handle this error
        return this.transitionTo('login');
      }

      // Return true to bubble this event to any parent route.
      return true;
    }
  }
```

But it can not redirect to the login page.
Any help please.

Comment: Is the action code in your indexroute and have you defined your login route in the router.js. mind showing your router.js?

Comment: Looks like this was answered by ember-simple-auth owner: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25708389/4950029

Comment: @wenincode Yes. The login route in my routes.js .

Comment: @Artych Thanks. But the answered use ember data. I cound not use. My model use Ember.Object.

Comment: Did you configure the `crossOriginWhitelist` (http://ember-simple-auth.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#SimpleAuth-Configuration-crossOriginWhitelist)? If not, Ember Simple Auth will not include the `Authorization` header in requests to 3rd origins.